# Does master page get called first?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, master-pages

I would assume this is true, but wanted to throw this question up. Is the master page executed first in ASP.NET, or does the page which is getting retrieved?

I am asking because I want some processing to be done in the master page, results of which are loaded into a static object and which can then be used by the called page (for instance user data)

Comment: Did you check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10505479/1379794)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sorry for just quoting, but i don't know what to add:

> Individual ASP.NET server controls have their own life cycle that is
>   similar to the page life cycle. For example, a control's Init and Load
>   events occur during the corresponding page events.
>
> Although both Init and Load recursively occur on each control, they
>   happen in reverse order. The Init event (and also the Unload event)
>   for each child control occur before the corresponding event is raised
>   for its container (bottom-up). However the Load event for a container
>   occurs before the Load events for its child controls (top-down).
>   **Master pages behave like child controls on a page: the master page
>   Init event occurs before the page Init and Load events, and the master
>   page Load event occurs after the page Init and Load events.**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

[image]

Comment: I think it's OK to quote the documentation while also providing a link. The quote brings reader to solution more quickly - plus, I believe you likely streamlined the doc, given the OP's question as context.  I found the detail to my answer in the image you put up front in your answer. Makes for a useful post.

Answer (score 8):

### **<kbd>Execution Priority</kbd>**

> 1. Content Page
> 2. Master Page
> 3. User Control

Answer (score 4):

Most page events will get called before the corresponding ones on the master page are (in essence the master page is considered a *part* of the page it is linked to - it is a user control).

See [ASP.Net 2.0 - Master Pages: Tips, Tricks, and Traps](http://odetocode.com/articles/450.aspx)  on OdeToCode for details.

Comment: Master page is actually a user control :)

Answer (score 0):

you could look at the .net documentation which states when and in what order events are called

see [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2009/03/08/asp-net-page-events-lifecycle.aspx), [this](http://odetocode.com/articles/450.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)