# Where in the page life cycle is the master page's load event (not OnLoad nor Page_Load)?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, page-lifecycle

My understanding of the page life cycle is as follows:

1. Page Page_PreInit
2. MasterPage Page_Init
3. Page Page_Init
4. Page Page_InitComplete
5. Page Page_PreLoad
6. Page Page_Load
7. MasterPage Page_Load
8. Page_LoadComplete
9. Page_PreRender
10. MasterPage Page_PreRender
11. Page Page_PreRenderComplete
12. Page Page_SaveStateComplete
13. MasterPage Page_Unload
14. Page Page_Unload

Given the above, where does the MasterPage's Load event fire?  Google isn't helping as quite a lot of people say Load when talking about the OnLoad event.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10505409/284240

Comment: @TimSchmelter The way it talks about Init and Load in the linked article makes it look like it is talking about the OnInit and OnLoad events.  That wouldn't be the only MSDN page saying one but meaning the other.

Comment: No, it's the `Init` and `Load` event, you can see the difference in the image.

Answer (score 2):

Master Page load event is between Content page Load event and Master page controls Load event.

Check the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3%28v=vs.140%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for details

> Although both Init and Load recursively occur on each control, they
>   happen in reverse order. The Init event (and also the Unload event)
>   for each child control occur before the corresponding event is raised
>   for its container (bottom-up). However the Load event for a container
>   occurs before the Load events for its child controls (top-down).
>   Master pages behave like child controls on a page: **the master page
>   Init event occurs before the page Init and Load events, and the master
>   page Load event occurs after the page Init and Load events.**

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: So does it call Masterpage(MP)'s OnLoad, which calls every event attached to MP's Load EventHandler, which includes the Page_Load function, all of which occurs on spot 7 in the list I gave?  So attaching a new event to MP's Load would be in spot 7 after OnLoad and after the Page_Load (per current implementation of EventHandlers)?

Answer (score 0):

The following is the sequence in which events occur when a master page is merged with a content page:

> 1. Content page PreInit event.
> 2. Master page controls Init event.
> 3. Content controls Init event.
> 4. Master page Init event.
> 5. Content page Init event.
> 6. Content page Load event.
> 7. Master page Load event.
> 8. Master page controls Load event.
> 9. Content page controls Load event.
> 10. Content page PreRender event.
> 11. Master page PreRender event.
> 12. Master page controls PreRender event.
> 13. Content page controls PreRender event.
> 14. Master page controls Unload event.
> 15. Content page controls Unload event.
> 16. Master page Unload event.
> 17. Content page Unload event.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3%28v=vs.140%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396